# video js forwording is not working with django in chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, video, html5-video, video.js

Video js is not working in chrome (latest version) with django 1.8. It is working well in firefox and IE. In chrome, video is playing well but when i click on the scrum to forward and backward video, video restarts again. I also tried with CDN but It result same:

```
<video id="ml_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup="{}" width="100%" height="400px" src="{{ mn_video.url }}">

        <source src="{{ mn_video.url }}" type='video/webm'></source>
        <source src="{{ mn_video.url }}" type='video/mp4'></source>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider 
            upgrading to a web browser that 
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
                supports HTML5 video
            </a>
        </p>
    </video>
```

**NOTE:**

- I tried it with django development server as well as with gunicorn.
- I do not get any error in console as well as in terminal.

Comment: What version of chrome and video.js are you using exactly? I'm using video.js with django 1.8 and it works fine for me …

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers As I said in my question, latest both are updated. I also tried Video.js v4.10.2 but result was same.

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers have you done any specific config other than mention on home page of videojs.com?